# How to make an admin create/edit post page to look like taxonomy page?

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-admin, taxonomy

This idea just came to me, where I thought it would be great to have something like this for CPTs that doesn't need much content/fields to fill out.

Basically a Post page where your able to add a post, as well as see the other posts in a list-table next to edit. For instance like the picture below:

[image: Post Page that looks like Taxonomy Admin Page]

Of course, there will be no use for WYSIWYGs, but I think this would be great for simple CPTs if this is something we're able to create in the Admin page.

Would love to know if this is possible, or examples of something similar if you seen such a thing.

Comment: Cool idea, mental note taken for when I find a similar interface in some plugin :) I know of [this one](http://wordpress.org/plugins/wedevs-project-manager/) with quite a creative interface, but haven't examined its inner workings.

Answer (score 0):

yes, that is a cool idea!

this kind of already happens in the quick edit, if you think about it... you just have to find the code that generates the quick edit and put it on the side like in the layout you showed.

another way to go about it, look into this tutorial, which you may be familiar with:
http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/reusable-custom-meta-boxes-part-1-intro-and-basic-fields/
but try to apply this to the 'posts page' instead of 'create/edit post page'

let me know how it goes and if you run into problems

Comment: 'Categories' are not post types. They are a taxonomy. The two are very different.

Comment: yes yes yes, they are obviously totally different.... and yes, i am stretching the definition of a post type very liberally. but in the back-end, i can see how it is treated as a built in custom post type (wired to be completely different from a post or page, of course).

Comment: okay, i do take it back... i thought that they were treated differently in the database... but you can still do what Roc asked for, since it is done to a much smaller degree in the quick edit and it is also done in the categories page (regardless of wether or not tags or cats are post types - everything is just strings in tables in the database in the end)

Comment: Please edit or delete this answer so that it does cause confusion for future visitors.